# DataGridView databound combobox displayed text disappears on mouse over

Tags: datagridview, combobox, databound

I have a DataGridView control with two databound combobox columns. When a user adds a row and selects a value in the first combobox column the second column only offers appropriate values from the databound table. An example might be Countries in the first column and appropriate Cities in the second. My problem is that, if the user passes his mouse over the earlier records in the table, column 2 will become blank wherever column 1 does not show the same Country that was selected in the newly added row.  The earlier rows have all been set to ReadOnly, and the column 2 values are still present, it's just that the databound display value no longer appears.

What can I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of anyone else who encounters this problem, I found the answer at:
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?632526-RESOLVED-DataGridView-ComboBox-Columns